# Reflection Exception in Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I tried `composer dump-autoload`, `composer update` and other commands when i run command related to php artisan I am getting error

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /media/durga/CE4C15B14C159575/htdocs/nyfrag/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738`

My Laravel project is running but artisan commands not working when i run any command related to php artisan it is showing above error. Could anybody please help me

my composer.json file is `{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*"

```
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"

    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"repositories": {
    "repo-name": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:jamisonvalenta/Laravel-4-Generators.git"
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Can you show us your composer.json file and your main controller namespace please? It's kinda related to a mismatch between your composer.json expected psr-4 configuration and your app files.

Comment: @subzeta thank you for your quick reply, where can i find main controller namespace?

Comment: Hey there! I mean your controllers common namespace. Or just copy here one of your controllers.

Comment: oh !! it is namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: Can you try to remove your entire vendor folder and make a composer install again?

Comment: yes i tried as you suggested, but got the same error what i was posted above